How can this series be calculated? $\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2}{1+x^2} + \frac{4}{1+x^4}+\frac{8}{1+x^8} +\cdot\cdot\cdot $
How can this series be calculated? $$\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2}{1+x^2} + \frac{4}{1+x^4}+\frac{8}{1+x^8} +\cdot\cdot\cdot $$
we have :
\begin{align}
S(x) & =\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2}{1+x^2} + \frac{4}{1+x^4}+\frac{8}{1+x^8} +\cdot\cdot\cdot
\\[5mm] & =\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{2^k}{1+x^{2^k}}=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}2^k(-x^{2^k})^i=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\sum^{\infty}_{i=0}(-1)^i2^k(x^{2^k})^i
\end{align}
We have stopped finding the solution. I tried some other ideas but they did not work. I found this problem in a book.
SUMMATION OF SERIES COLLECTED BY L. B. W. JOLLEY, M.A. (cantab.), M.I.E.E. page 18 proplem 91
